# How to embedd a 3D cloth on human body using Kinect and XNA

Tags: model, 3d, kinect, xna-4.0

I'm doing a virtual dressing room type project with kinect and XNA. But I don't know how to map a 3D model to the body covering all the body area. I have tried the Avataaring-XNA sample
and could add the background as the video coming from Kinect. But the thing is the 3D Model(Dude.fbx) is not moving with the human real body and not covering the whole body. Any help would be so much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help http://mopred.blogspot.com/2012/11/changing-avateering-avatar-in-kinect.html with this you can change the model to anyone you like, I've tried and it works perfectly. You mention that you added the background as the video coming from the kinect, I want to add the model 3d in foreground and the video data in background, could you help me at that?

Comment: i have same problem you hav efound any solution then help me